# android drawing on photos

Tags: android, draw, exif, photos

I am looking to be pointed in the right direction for help.  What I want to do is take a picture, and then be able to highlight certain aspects of it (i.e circle a door, comment on a color) right onto the picture.  Basically what a Samsung note can do.  What android package would I be looking at?  What it looks like to me, is that I would use the picture as a canvas and then draw on top of the canvas(which is the picture), is that it basically summed up?  Or am I missing something?

Another thing that I would like to do with the picture is add data for future identification.  I know android has their Exif Interface for this, but what I cant seem to find any information on is, it possible to create my own tags for this class? For example adding a "who took it" tag.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need a custom view and override the `onDraw` method of the view. In the `onDraw` method you get a reference to a Canvas object. From there, you can do most of whatever drawing you need. If you want to take user input and draw with it, you're going to have to override the touch events, and keep track of what you want to draw and then draw in the `onDraw` method.

As for Exif data. If you want to develop for before Android 2.0, then you need a 3rd party library, I use [sanselanandroid](http://code.google.com/p/sanselanandroid/) personally. If you don't care about pre 2.0, I head `ExifInterface` works well too. It looks like you can save any arbitrary tag using `ExifInterface` because it just uses a string tag, and then string value, but know that only your app will know to read that tag.